# How to perform calculations on moving subsets of n elements of data frame without loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate Effective Drought Index using R. One of many steps needed to do so is calculate a stored water quantity (EP):

EP365=P1/1+(P1+P2)/2+(P1+P2+P3)/3+(P1+P2+P3+P4)/4+ … +(P1+…+P365)/365

Where P1 is daily precipitation last day, P2 is precipitation two day ago and P365 is precipitation 365 days ago. Calculation of EP must be done for each 365-day period starting with day 1 to 365, 2 to 366 etc.

So I have a dataframe with two columns: date and precip and more than 20000 rows. Simple (and slow) solution is calculate any subset of 365 elements from row 365 to nrow(df):

```
period_length <- 365
df$EP <- NA
for (i in (period_length:nrow(df))) {
  first <- (i - period_length) + 1
  SUB <- rev(df[first:i,]$prcp) 
  EP <- sum(cumsum(SUB)/seq_along(SUB)) 
  df$EP[i] <- EP
}


Of course it works, however the question is how to calculate EP without using loop?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rollapplyr` with the indicated function.  Replace `fill=NA` with `partial=TRUE` if you want it to work with fewer than 365 days during the first 364 points or omit both if you want to drop the first 364 points.

```
library(zoo)
x <- 1:1000 # sample data
ep <- rollapplyr(x, 365, function(x) sum(cumsum(x) / seq_along(x)), fill = NA)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is it :)  Of course I must do rev(x) in my case. Pity that I can't feedback this answer :(

Comment: No problem @Piotr. I can do that :)